# fetch data from two tables in MYSQL query not working

Tags: java, mysql

Below is the two table `Vehicle` and `vehicle_owner`

VEHICLE_OWNER TABLE

```
**Oid   Oname     Oage     Oaddress**                                
1     Ahsan     22       house 80/3 street no 22 rawalpindi 
2     Arslan    23       House no 56-C F6/2 Islamabad
```

VEHICLE TABLE

```
**Vregno  Vname   Vmakername Vtype    Vyear       Vstatus      V_oid**
FSM393  Mehran  Suzuki     Car      2006        Clear          1
RLA3725 City    Honda      Car      2013        Stolen         2
```

Code:

```
PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("select Vstatus,Oname from Vehicle_Owner LEFT OUTER JOIN Vehicle ON vehicle_owner.Oid= Vehicle.V_oid where Vregno='"+ss+"'"); 
ResultSet r=p.executeQuery(); 
while(r.next()) { 
    vstatus=r.getString("Vstatus"); 
    oname=r.getString("Oname"); 
    System.out.println("Vehicle Status= "+vstatus+"<br>"); 
    System.out.println("Owner name= "+oname+"<br>");
}
```

i wanna display the Oname and Vstatus against the vehicle registartion no. (Vregno) i m using this query but its not work in MYSQL

```
select Vstatus,Oname from Vehicle_Owner INNER JOIN Vehicle ON vehicle.V_oid= vehicle_owner.Oid AND Vregno="FSM393";
```

ANYONE PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: The query seems fine. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Please use SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Query is ok, problem is somewhere else...

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83810/3 seems fine to me...

Comment: it display nothing PreparedStatement p=conn.prepareStatement("select Vstatus,Oname from Vehicle_Owner LEFT OUTER JOIN Vehicle ON vehicle_owner.Oid= Vehicle.V_oid where Vregno='"+ss+"'");
            ResultSet r=p.executeQuery();
            
             while(r.next())
                               {
               vstatus=r.getString("Vstatus");
                oname=r.getString("Oname");
                   
       System.out.println("Vehicle Status= "+vstatus+"<br>");
               System.out.println("Owner name= "+oname+"<br>");

Comment: Updated question to add your code and Java tag